# Limit of sequences added to each other

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Evaluating the following question

$$a_n = 4^{-5(3^{n+4})} + 2^{-3^n} + 2$$

I am trying to understand the convergence of the following sequence and so when taking the $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ of the above sequence the limit is 2

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 2 $$

I am trying to work out the convergence rate using the following expression

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - r|}{|x_n - r|} $$

When substituting i get the following:-

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|4^{-5(3^{n+4+1})} + 2^{-3^{n+1}} + 2 - 2|}{|4^{-5(3^{n+4})} + 2^{-3^n} + 2 - 2|} $$

$\implies$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|4^{-5(3^{n+4+1})} + 2^{-3^{n+1}} |}{|4^{-5(3^{n+4})} + 2^{-3^n} |} $$

I am not sure how to go about breaking down this expressions to evaluate the limit as n tends to infinity can anyone help me evaluate this expression to find the convergence rate.

Comment: Dividing numerator and denominator by $2^{-3^n}$, I get that the limit is $0$.  Note that we can write $4^{-5\cdot{3^{-n}}}=2^{-10\cdot{3^{-n}}}$ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

By defining $u=3^n$:

$${4^{-5(3^{n+4+1})}=4^{-5(243u)}=\left({1\over 4^{1215}}\right)^u 
\\2^{-3^{n+1}}=2^{-3u}=\left({1\over 8}\right)^u \\4^{-5(3^{n+4})}=4^{-5(81u)}=\left({1\over 4^{405}}\right)^u \\2^{-3^n}=\left({1\over 2}\right)^u}$$Can you finish now?

Comment: im a bit confused honestly trying to work through the substitution @Mostafa

Comment: Ok, where is your ambiguity?

Comment: how did you get 243u thats confusing to me

Comment: Based on the relation $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$ we can deduce that $$3^{n+4+1}{=3^{n+5}\\=3^n\cdot 3^5\\=243\cdot 3^n\\=243u}$$

Comment: ok got that so far so when i make these substitutions into the original expressions in terms evaluating the limit i would consider what happens when U goes to infinity? @Mostafa